# Loop through dictionary error : type (key:Int, value: Any) does not conform to protocol sequence -

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary

I have a dictionary as `[Int: Any]()`

my code:

```
var test = [Int: Any]()
test = self.header_all_items[header] as! [Int : Any]
for tes in test{
    for (key:value)in tes{ // error line
        print(key)
    }
}
```

I got this error :

```
type (key:Int, value: Any) does not conform to protocol sequence
```

Comment: why not just print tes.0 ?

Comment: You are traversing as array, try as dictionary: for (key, value) in test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be

```
var test = [[Int: Any]]()

//assign your header

for tes in test{

    for (key, value) in tes{ // error line
        print("\(key)")
    }
}
```

So first of all:

- You must have an array of dictionary and not just a dictionary: `[[Int: Any]]`
- Change your last `for` to `for (key, value) in tes`

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want to iterate over your dictionary, if so then below code may help you

```
let test = self.header_all_items[header] as! [Int : Any]

for (key, value) in test {
  print("\(key)")
}
```